# How do I use the String.format() method in Java for 2 numbers involved in subtraction? One a whole number and the other a double to 1dp?

Tags: java, string.format

My code:

```
double num = 223.23;

String result = ("The timer says: " + Integer.parseInt(String.format("%.1f", num)) - Integer.parseInt(String.format("%.0f", num/60.0)));
```

The error:

```
Compilation failed (12/02/2021 16:59:03)
Error: line 1 - bad operand types for binary operator '-'
  first type:  java.lang.String
  second type: int
```

I realize that both of the operands must be compatible for the `-` operator to be used. I am trying to subtract a whole number from a decimal number to get a result representing tenths. i.e, in this instance `.2`

Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, i.e. what is the desired String?

Comment: I am looking for a string to print the time in minutes, seconds and tenths of seconds. Something like:  "The timer says: 4 minutes 32.5 seconds

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the minutes as a whole number you should use a different data type. `.0f` causes something like 3.7 to be rounded up to 4 minutes.

To be more concise I would calculate the values beforehand and then put them into the String format.

This should do the trick:

```java
 double num = 223.23;
 int minutes = (int) num / 60;
 double seconds = num % 60;

 String result = String.format("The timer says %d minutes %.1f seconds", minutes, seconds);
```

Comment: Without giving me the answer, could you please say if it is possible to display the specs mentioned using the String.format() method. Thanks.

Comment: it sure is possible, but that would just involve unnecessarily converting something back and forth. You cannot directly use `Integer.parseInt` on a floating point value. `Double.parseDouble` or `Float.parseFloat` would be needed

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the first operand:

```
"The timer says: " +
```

That will convert everything into a String, then you use a `-` operator in the same statement using the operator in the `String` result of:

```
"The timer says: " + Integer.parseInt(String.format("%.1f", num))
```

resulting in the bad operator for Strings

You can use parenthesis to precede the string evaluation by isolating the number part:

```
"The timer says: " + (Integer.parseInt(String.format("%.1f", num)) - Integer.parseInt(String.format("%.0f", num/60.0)))
```

This way the result of the parenthesis will be added to the String.

Comment: Marcos Vasconcelos, No matter if I isolate either one or the other or both of the number parts the workspace that I am using keeps producing the same error message:                            bad operand types for binary operator '-'
  first type:  java.lang.String
  second type: int                         . What editor are you using that produces the correct outcome?

Comment: This answer won't run - NumberFormatException

Comment: I'm using JDoodle ```System.out.println("s" + (1-1));```

Comment: Try JDoodle on your answer `System.out.println("The timer says: " + (Integer.parseInt(String.format("%.1f", num)) - Integer.parseInt(String.format("%.0f", num/60.0))));`